# MariaDB like-search over multiple columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to search for orders matching my searchvalue in at least one of multiple searchfields.
The searchvalue doesn't have to be at the start and the searchfields are varchar of different sizes.

There is no index on any searchfield yet.
However, a index on company_no, status and appointment_date already exists.

Requests against bigger datasets take seconds.

My current MariaDB-Version is 11.0.2

```sql
SELECT 
    o.order_no
FROM 
    order AS o
WHERE 
    o.company_no = 297
    AND o.status IN ('open','progress') 
    AND ( 
        o.v_vin LIKE '%searchvalue%' 
        OR o.v_brand LIKE '%searchvalue%' 
        OR o.v_model LIKE '%searchvalue%' 
        OR o.v_license_number LIKE '%searchvalue%' 
        OR o.c_first_name LIKE '%searchvalue%' 
        OR o.c_last_name LIKE '%searchvalue%'
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    o.appointment_date desc;
```

the current executionplan looks like this:

```
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key                                 | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                              |
---
| 1  | SIMPLE      | o     | ref  | idx_company_branch_status_appt_date | idx_company_branch_status_appt_date | 5       | const | 89286 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
```

How can I optimize the query?

Comment: Please include the current execution plan.

Comment: @TheImpaler I've added the execution plan

Comment: [Full text indexes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-indexes/) will have some gains, however consider a [full text search engine](https://medevel.com/os-fulltext-search-solutions/), those developers have dedicated many hours to this problem.